# which view get all information about all data dictionary views?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

I need data dictionary view that gets all info about all data dictionary view details in oracle

```
select * from user_dba;

desc dba_directiories;
```

Answer (score 5):

It is called dictionary.

Looks like this:

```
SQL> desc dictionary
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TABLE_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(30)
 COMMENTS                                           VARCHAR2(4000)
```

You can query it like this (for example, searching for ones that talk about "constraints"):

```
SQL> select * From dictionary where lower(comments) like '%constraint%';

TABLE_NAME                COMMENTS
------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
ALL_CONSTRAINTS           Constraint definitions on accessible tables
ALL_CONS_COLUMNS          Information about accessible columns in constraint
                           definitions

USER_CONSTRAINTS          Constraint definitions on user's own tables
USER_CONS_COLUMNS         Information about accessible columns in constraint
                           definitions


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query on system-supplied DICTIONARY view which contains the names and abbreviated descriptions of all data dictionary views.

**SELECT * FROM DICTIONARY ORDER BY 1**

It has mainly divided into 3 sets. So the views with 
- **Prefix DBA_** show all relevant information in the entire database. DBA_ views are intended only for administrators.
- **Prefix ALL_** refer to the user's overall perspective of the database. These views return information about schema objects to which the user has access through public or explicit grants of privileges and roles, in addition to schema objects that the user owns.
- **Prefix USER_** views most likely to be of interest to typical database users are those with the prefix USER_.